# Symfony2 Can't install TCPDFBundle with composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

On my current symfony 2.2.1 project,  I want to install TCPDFBundle (bundle for generating PDF documents)

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

So after a long time waiting for cloning, it says that time is out.

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RunTimeException]
The process time-out
```

any help for this error?

Comment: try replacing with "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "dev-master", and also this is not a bundle it's just the library i believe

Comment: I forget to mention, I've tried "dev-master" before, but I had the same error as with "*".

Comment: update your composer with composer `--self-update` and then try with this version `"tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.0.018"`

Comment: I did what you said, but now i have a new error saying: the contents of http://packagist.org/p/provider-archived$c7e173...f41f3.json do not much its signature. This should -in-the-middle attack. try running composer and report this if you think it is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle`? 
This bundle makes it easy to use the TCPDF library.
Just add this to `composer.json` like this

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "dev-master"
}
```

After this, follow the instructions in this link

- https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle

Comment: are there instructions for installing in symfony 3?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=30000 php composer.phar install
```

It means, that you should change timeout parameter in order to be able to install this requirement.